# How to use status panel in grafana? Or suggest the best visualization toll

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I just wanna monitor whether an endpoint is up or not that's it. I can return a simple JSON as shown below

localhost:8080/status
{ "status" : "UP/Down/Critical"}

I want to show this simple information in Grafana real-time

Currently I'm using Infinity Datasource or Sample JSON data source. I intend to use Status panel visualization tool, which is not working.

Moreover, in grafana-api is saw datasource field, which I don't know How to use.

A newbee to Grafana

Answer (score 0):

you should totally be able to visualize status using this plugin, if your source data is pure json.

1. please clarify whether the data is `localhost:8080/status { "status" : "UP/Down/Critical"}` or `{ "status" : "UP/Down/Critical"}`
2. please clarify what do you mean by "not working"

in general the best way to ask such questions is to at least write what you did, what you expected and what you actually got.
Much better option is to quote commands/settings, and show output examples/screenshots.